# Is is normal for brakes to lock if braking too hard while wearing in new brake pads. 2000 Holden Frontera UES V6

Tags: brakes

3 days ago I had my brake pads,rotors,calipers and disc replaced. The mechanic told me to take it easy on the brakes while they are in wearing stage. Today  I was going about 40km and Im not sure if i hit the brakes too hard but as I went to brake and slow down the pedal would not push down and the brakes locked. Once stopped they were no longer locked and i continued to drive home and take caution with braking and nothing happened. Did I most likely brake too hard or does it sound like there's still a problem with my brakes. Also my ABS light is always on

Make: Holden

Model: Frontera UES

Year: 2000

KMS: 210000

Engine: V6

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You should get the ABS figured out before you worry about the brakes themselves, especially since you've just had the brakes, rotors, and calipers replaced. Also, please edit your question with the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question.

Comment: Ok thank you. So I should go back to my mechanic who did my brakes get ABS looked at?

Comment: If you don't have the means to check it yourself, then yes.

Comment: If your ABS light is on, that means you do no have a working anti-lock braking system. Your breaks still can work, but during a hard breaking (or even medium or light breaking on slippery/sandy roads) your wheels will lock. ABS is there to prevent these kind of wheel lock situations by monitoring wheel speeds, and releasing brake force on wheels that are blocking to avoid uncontrollable slipping.

Comment: BTW it is nothing to do with new brake pads. If your brakes are new, it could be that brake force is less for a while, so drive carefully with new brakes. Avoid unneeded hard brakes also for first 100km or so - it could burn/warp your new brakes.

Comment: How much would it cost to fix my ABS problem and should I not drive until a mechanic has looked at it?

Comment: @gdqquino anywhere between 0 and very expensive... we can’t guess.